# Filter row based on counting the same thing value happening more

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, count

I have DataFrame where the "name" variable is sometimes repetitive. I want to filter only those row where we have the repetitive name. For example,

```
name=['A','B','C','A','C','A']
value=[4,7,8,9,7,6]
a=pd.DataFrame(name, value)
a.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
a.columns=['Value','Name']
a
```

Now I want to filter and create another DataFrame where we have only those row where same names occurs at least twice. Like for this one I don't want the row that include `B` as it occurs only once, like in the image:

[image]

I think, I might need to use something like count and unique or something like that in the condition

Comment: Just a heads up: you can much more easily instantiate your dataframe with `pd.DataFrame({"name": name, "value": value})`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `duplicated` with `keep=False`. It marks all duplicates as True, so what the below code does is it filters out all rows without any duplicates.

```
out = a[a['Name'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
   Value Name
0      4    A
2      8    C
3      9    A
4      7    C
5      6    A
```

If we want to filter rows with a certain number of "Name" occurrences, we could use `value_counts` + `map`:

```
out = a[a['Name'].map(a['Name'].value_counts()>=3)]
```

or `groupby` + `size`:

```
out = a[a.groupby('Name')['Value'].transform('count')>=3]
```

Output:

```
   Value Name
0      4    A
3      9    A
5      6    A
```

Comment: What if I want the rows where name occurs at least 3 times(basically a certain number of times)?

Comment: @ash1 please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
a[a["Name"].apply(lambda x: a["Name"].tolist().count(x)) >= 2]
```

##### Output

|  | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | A |
| 2 | 8 | C |
| 3 | 9 | A |
| 4 | 7 | C |
| 5 | 6 | A |

If you are intersted in having the values based on the repetition number, you can use:

```py
repNum = 3
a[a["Name"].apply(lambda x: a["Name"].tolist().count(x)) == 3]
```

##### Output

|  | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | A |
| 3 | 9 | A |
| 5 | 6 | A |

I suggest to initialize `a["Name"].tolist()` before using it in the apply function since it might be more efficient:

```py
nameList = a["Name"].tolist()
# Rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `groupby` `transform` `count`

```
cnt = a.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('count')
n = 3
a[cnt==n]
Out[166]: 
   Value Name
0      4    A
3      9    A
5      6    A
```